# Java Runtime Environment Or Other Issue?

Tags: java, linux

My operating system is working with the java version "1.6.0_24"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.11.90) (rhel-1.62.1.11.11.90.el6_4-x86_64)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

When I run WhiteboxGAT(http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml) under Linux, which is an open source GIS software running in the java 8u20 environment, it is said:

```
[junting@orc130 Whitebox_3_2_1]$ java -jar WhiteboxGIS.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: whiteboxgis/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: whiteboxgis.Main. Program will exit.
```

I am wondering did I use the right JAVA runtime environment? And based on the problem, what should I do?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your Java is pretty far back-level.  I'm thinking that version 52 needs Java 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

You really don't see the problem?

> IcedTea**6**
>
> GIS software running in the **java 8**u20

Comment: Thank you all! I am a new java user, and I don't know which  version of the java I am using and which version of the java I should install or update. I just try to run the WhiteboxGAT in a Sharcnet  computer, which is the largest high performance computing consortium (www.sharcnet.ca). So should I install or update java with the java server  edition or java runtime edition? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your class was compiled with a newer version of java, update your jvm

Comment: Thank you. what does jvm mean?

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering did I use the right JAVA runtime environment?

You didn't.

You need a Java 8 environment to run code that has been compiled with Java 8 as the target.  The exception clearly says that you are running Java 8 target code on Java 6, and that doesn't work.

---

There is another (much stronger) reason to upgrade your Java release.

- Java 6 is old, and is no longer receiving security patches.  (Unless you are using Oracle Java, and you are paying for support!)
- You are not even running the latest public version of Java 6 ... by a long way.
- And you are apparently running Java in your web browser.

All this means that your browser will be vulnerable to all sorts of Java-based attack vectors, any one of which could result in your system's security being compromised.

Be afraid ... and fix this vulnerability ASAP.  And I'd look at other security practices as well.  Are you applying security patches from the distro channels?  Are you monitoring / reviewing security logs?  Are you backing up?

Comment: Thank you. Now I make sure that I need to update my java, but which version or edition should I update: Java runtime or Java server editon?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You should update whatever version you are using.  If you have a JRE installation, update that.  If you have a JDK installation, update that.  If you have are using 32 bit or 64 bit, update that.  If you don't understand, read the description of whatever it is you are considering, and figure out if it is what >>you<< need.